# SQL Query fails while running in SQLCMD Mode

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

I need help, I am writing the SQL code shown below for extracting data from multiple servers from the SSMS window of one SQL Server. I have CMC on SERVER1 and have registered SERVER2 as well and all looks good.

But I have a issue in this code:

```
:CONNECT SERVER1
USE [SOURCE_NAP]
SELECT [CUST_ID]
FROM [SOURCE_NAP].[dbo].[Customer] 
GO
EXCEPT

:CONNECT SERVER2
USE [NAP]
SELECT [CUST_ID]
FROM [NAP].[dbo].[Customer] 
GO
```

When I execute individual selects with `:CONNECT` above them it works fine but when I want to display the output using an `EXCEPT` between there two selects, I get this error:

```
Connecting to SERVER1...
Disconnecting connection from SERVER1...
Connecting to SERVER2...
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'NNSW_NAP.dbo.[Customer]'

```
Disconnecting connection from SERVER2...
```

Seems like before connecting to another instance it tries to disconnect from earlier instance and hence this error. Any way to fix this else Is there any alternate way around to query data from multiple server and then using `EXCEPT/UNION` etc between them ???

Thanks

Comment: The code as written would give you the error `incorrect syntax near the keyword 'except'`. What code are you really running? In any case, you can't execute a single query across batches (batches are things separated by `go` in SSMS) The `go` basically means "send everything up to here to SQL Server and wait for a response".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot separate the batches by introducing `GO` in the middle. You should have them as single batch.

```sql
:connect SERVER1
SELECT [CUST_ID]
FROM [SOURCE_NAP].[dbo].[Customer] 
EXCEPT
:connect SERVER2
SELECT [CUST_ID]
FROM [NAP].[dbo].[Customer]
GO
```